# How can I convert days into weeks and days

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, modulo

I have a date range say 1-Jul-2016 to 10-Jul-2016. I want to extract number of weeks and remaining days exists in that range like

No. of Weeks = 1

No. of Remaining Days = 3

So for this case the answer i want to see is 1.3 
I know how to find days OR week difference using

```
DATEDIFF(DAY,@ArrivalDate,@DepartureDate)
DATEDIFF(WEEK,@ArrivalDate,@DepartureDate)
```

But how to find and get whether a date contains only full Weeks or Weeks and Days.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Simply  `floor(Days/7,0)` to get your weeks and use `mod(Days,7)` to get days remainder  functions may vary slightly based on RDBMS but you'd need to tag the question with what database & version you're on to help much further.   (Substitute your datediff formula for Days in the above

Comment: thank you for your suggestion , it's tsql is the database i use

Comment: Which limits it to SQL Server and Sybase I believe.  Still don't know version.  Now with regards to "how it contains full weeks... How do we know what Day of week your week starts on or do we just count 7 consecutive days as a "Week"?  so lets say we start on Tuesday and wrap around a full week + 2 days to thursday  Would that be 0 weeks and 9 days or 1 week 2 days?

Comment: we just 7 consecutive days as a week, actually i want to use this for age so it doesnt matter what is the week start

Comment: thanks for the answer i'll and let you know the result.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

- (Days/7) as weeks  (Get a int result so it's always a whole number)
- `Modulus` (Days `% 7` as days)  (gets you the remainder days of a week)

.

```
SELECT datediff(DAY,@ArrivalDate,@Departure) / 7 as weeks
     , datediff(DAY,@ArrivalDate,@Departure) % 7 as days
```

[DEMO](https://rextester.com/DQZXEE8676)

Comment: Ah true. modified answer/demo

Comment: Side note: datediff does also take a WK specifier to give the number of weeks between two dates, but it's afflicted somewhat by the typical datediff problem that it doesn't give the number of weeks between two dates, it gives the count of times the week boundary (midnight sunday) is crossed, so `select datediff(wk,'20170107','20170108')` which is Saturday to Sunday gives a result as "1 week" when it's actually only one day..

Comment: as such, the approach of going to a finer level of precision (day) and dividing is advisable, though note that it can still technically give rise to an error in that Sunday 1st at 23:59:59 to Sunday 8th 00:00:01 is technically only 6 days and 2 seconds, but datediff reports it as 7 days because the "midnight" date boundary has been crossed over 7 times.. Depending on the precision required, one might choose to `datediff(second, …)/86400` etc

Comment: @CaiusJard  isn't that always the case?  how precise?  "What denotes a "Day" 24 hours or crossing a timezones midnight boundary?  How do we know that arrivaldate and departure date are in the same timezone?  I love date/time questions.   I just went with the basics and said a any time w/in a new "date" boundary was considered 1. As with many questions/problems answers are only as precise as the definitions given for the words used ;P  Lets add in leap years and leapseconds to boot!\

Comment: I tend to think of date math related questions in the oracle sense, where end date minus start date is a float number of days, and a day is 24h or 86400 seconds etc - 6am Sunday minus 6pm Saturday is half a day. Though I wish it werent thus, datediff inaccuracy tends not to matter so long as you're aware of it and adjust solutions accordingly.